# AngularJS updating scope variable from a directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, packery

I am working on a widget panel in [angular](https://angularjs.org/) and [packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co/).

What I am trying to do is bind the order set by [packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co/) after dragging an element to the scope variable 'order' on my $scope items so I can do things like save the order later. I came across $apply method, but I'm not sure how to call it correctly. I am new to angular. Any help appreciated.

```
   scope.$apply(function () {
      scope.items[i].order = (i + 1);
   });
```

Please see my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/7c3ff83f/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be completely honest, its getting kind of confusing. You should check out angularjs ui-draggable that takes care all of that.

Your current problem is that you're mapping incorrectly between itemElem and indexes,

NOw, this is not the best solution, but it demonstrates the problem you're having:

Modify the code to be:

```
                   var index = parseInt($(itemElem)
                  .find('span.TX')
                  .text()); 

                  scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.items[index].order =i+1;
                  });
```

and add `<span class="TX">{{$index}}</span>` to item template.

http://jsfiddle.net/xzgc9aq7/

Comment: Thanks! I know it's a mess. But I'm not sure how to properly separate the logic yet. Appreciate the help.